# How to hide the header for web tab

Tags: visualforce, web-tab

We have created the salesforce web tab and given an link URL to Visualforce page, page works fine. But we need this page without header. I tried with **showheader=false** but it didn't work.

How do we hide the salesforce header for this?

Comment: Ok. I have created the visualforce page with <apex:page showheader=false /> and created the web tab for this page, when I click on this tab still I can see the salesforce header. My requirement is not to show the salesforce header after clicking on this web tab. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a **Visualforce tab** instead of **web tab**.

In web tab. Page load inside the body section so It will not hide the above header. It will only hide the loaded VF page header.

If you want to hide page Header then create **Visualforce tab** and select your visualforce page.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ratan, We have very specific reason for web tab. We tried with VF page tab, it works great. But we need it in web tab.

Comment: @techsolutions. Then you need to use javascript hack for hiding header. You can get the header element using javascript and make display none. Hope this will work

Comment: Can you post set of code if you have?

Comment: ok let me try this first

Comment: @techsolutions nope we can't use javascript for this. I dont thing there is another solution except VF tab.

Answer (score -1):

I found that showHeader="false" did not remove my header, perhaps this is a defect?

Therefore, I tried:

```
 <apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
       <iframe name="VisualForceLeads" src="/{your id here}?isdtp=mn"  height="1000" width="100%"></iframe>
    </apex:page>
```

and **this approach removes the sidebar and the header immediately.**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/38170)

Comment: @BorisBachovski Obsolutely it provides some clarification with web Tab. It will remove header and sidebar for WebTab.